# gcc inline assembler get error "lvalue required in asm statement"

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, avr

I need to write the C-code that does

```
DDRB &= ~pins;
```

with inline assembly (AVR). I never used it before. My attempt:

```
register uint8_t t1, t2; // temporary registers
__asm__ volatile (
    "in %[t1], %[w1_ddr]"   "\n\t"
    "mov %[t2], %[pins]"    "\n\t"
    "com %[t2]"             "\n\t"
    "and %[t1], %[t2]"      "\n\t"
    "out %[w1_ddr], %[t1]"  "\n\t"
    : [t1] "+r" (t1),
      [t2] "+r" (t2),
      [w1_ddr] "+I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRB))
    : [pins] "r" (pins)
);
```

`gcc` gives the following error `lvalue required in asm statement`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to write it in assembler? What's wrong with `DDRB &= ~pins;`?

Comment: @Keith: I use it in time-critical code and I should be sure about number of clock cycles that command spend. With C I can't be sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "I" constraint in AVR indicates that the operand is a constant. Hence it cannot be "+", i.e. input-output. Make it plain input, like this:

```
register uint8_t t1, t2; // temporary registers
__asm__ volatile (
    "in %[t1], %[w1_ddr]"   "\n\t"
    "mov %[t2], %[pins]"    "\n\t"
    "com %[t2]"             "\n\t"
    "and %[t1], %[t2]"      "\n\t"
    "out %[w1_ddr], %[t1]"  "\n\t"
    : [t1] "+r" (t1),
      [t2] "+r" (t2)
    : [w1_ddr] "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRB)),
      [pins] "r" (pins)
);
```

Comment: But I *write* to `w1_ddr` at last line. I should to say that `w1_ddr` is both input and output, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm a idiot. `w1_ddr` is a constant really. I can't delete previous comment.